# Regexextract number just before specific text Google sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, extract, re2

I need to extract the number that comes right before the text `Positions`

Example String:

`Medical Specialist (Anaestheologist) (4 Positions) at Ministry`

Valid Output should be `4`

Example String 2 (If text Positions doesn't exist)

`Medical Specialist (Anaestheologist) (4) at Ministry`

Valid Output

`4`

I tried:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A24,"\(.*Positions.*\)")` but it did not work.

Comment: Hint: A number is `\d*` and don't forget about the space that precedes "Positions" if it's present.

Comment: Hint 2: There are a lot of online regular expression labs where you can practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2; "(\d+)(?: Positions)?"))
```

[image]